# dynamic partition prunning not working in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

There are two tables: one big (T0), one small (T1). I run code below and expect it to use DPP, but it does not:

```py
df = spark.table('T0').select('A', 'B', 'C')
df1 = spark.table('T1').select('A')
df.join(F.broadcast(df1), ['A']).explain()
```

Then I do a hack and it starts working:

```py
values = [_.A for _ in df1.select('A').collect()]
values_type = ArrayType(StringType())
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([values], values_type).select(F.explode('value').alias('A'))
df.join(F.broadcast(df2), ['A']).explain()
```

In first case I see `BatchScan[...] T0 [filters=] RuntimeFilters: []`

And in second: `BatchScan[...] T0 [filters=] RuntimeFilters: [dynamicpruningexpression(A#5172 IN dynamicpruning#10343)]`

What is the difference between two cases? My guess was about `nullable = true` for `T1` but I tried both options (`nullable = true|false`) and it does not work in both.

Don't know if it is important, but I use Iceberg for data storage.