Dynamic partition pruning between large and small table without extra filter conditions
I have a large partitioned fact table and a small dimension table.
The partition column of the large table is the key column of the dimension table.
I would like to use the small table to reduce the number of partitions I read from the large table.
There is no condition other than that there has to be a small table record corresponding to each large table partition.
Both 'INNER JOIN' and 'LEFT SEMI JOIN' are acceptable here.
My problem is that I am not able to get dynamic partition pruning to kick in.
No matter what I do, all partitions of the large table are read.
How do I suggest to the query analyzer to use dynamic partition pruning?
Before I go into the details of my minimal working example, another observation:
When I research dynamic partition pruning, all examples usually include a filter condition on the dimension table.
When I set a non-selective filter condition on the small table in my minimal working example, dynamic partition pruning kicks in.
Before I translate this to my production use case, I need to better understand what happens under the hood.
Minimal working example
Code
import time

import requests
import pyspark.sql as ps

spark = ps.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Create a new schema with every script run.
ts = time.monotonic_ns()
schema_name = f"foo_{ts}"
spark.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE {schema_name}")

# Create large partitioned facts table.
records = [
    {"fact_id": i + 1, "fact_partition": i + 1}
    for i in range(1000)
]
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        {"fact_id": i + 1, "fact_partition": i + 1}
        for i in range(1000)
    ],
).write.partitionBy(
    "fact_partition",
).saveAsTable(
    f"{schema_name}.fact_table",
)
fact_table = spark.table(f"{schema_name}.fact_table")

# Create small dimension table.
records = [{"dim_key": 1, "dim_val": 1}]
spark.createDataFrame(
    [{"dim_key": 1, "dim_val": 1}],
).write.saveAsTable(
    f"{schema_name}.dim_table",
)
dim_table = spark.table(f"{schema_name}.dim_table")

# Transform dataframe, and trigger action.
res = fact_table.join(
    dim_table,
    fact_table["fact_partition"] == dim_table["dim_key"],
    how = "left_semi",
)
res.collect()

# Look up rows read in explanation.
res.explain("cost")

# Look up rows read in metrics.
apps = requests.get("http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications").json()
stages = requests.get(f"http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/{apps[0]['id']}/stages").json()

for stage_it in sorted(stages, key=lambda x: x["stageId"]):
    print(
        "{}\t{}\t{}".format(
            stage_it['inputRecords'],
            stage_it['name'],
            stage_it['details'].split('\n')[0],
        ),
    )

Execution
>>> python3 foo.py
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join LeftSemi, (fact_partition#11L = dim_key#20L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
:- Filter isnotnull(fact_partition#11L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
:  +- Relation foo_37205255539283.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
+- Project [dim_key#20L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=759.0 B)
   +- Filter isnotnull(dim_key#20L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
      +- Relation foo_37205255539283.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
+- == Final Plan ==
   *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [fact_partition#11L], [dim_key#20L], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
   :- *(2) ColumnarToRow
   :  +- FileScan parquet foo_37205255539283.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1000 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(fact_partition#11L)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fact_id:bigint>
   +- BroadcastQueryStage 0
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=57]
         +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(dim_key#20L)
            +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
               +- FileScan parquet foo_37205255539283.dim_table[dim_key#20L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_key#20L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/home/hansyu/Scratch/Cell/compass-spark-ops/spark-warehouse/foo_3..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_key)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint>
+- == Initial Plan ==
   BroadcastHashJoin [fact_partition#11L], [dim_key#20L], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
   :- FileScan parquet foo_37205255539283.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1000 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(fact_partition#11L)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fact_id:bigint>
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=44]
      +- Filter isnotnull(dim_key#20L)
         +- FileScan parquet foo_37205255539283.dim_table[dim_key#20L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_key#20L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_key)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint>


0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3725)
1       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:191)
1000    collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3725)

Comments
Both the query explanation and the Spark metrics tell me that all 1000 partitions in fact_table are read.
How do I get the query analyzer to (i) take the key columns of the small table (dim_key = 1), and (ii) prune the partitions of the large table (fact_partition = 1)?
Note that the BroadcastHashJoin and BuildRight already satisfies some of the prerequisites to dynamic partition pruning.
So what is missing here?
I have also tried to make the large table larger.
But it did not help.
And as I mentioned, a non-selective filter trigger dynamic partition pruning even when I do not increase the size ratio between large and small table.
What did I try?
Non-selective filter statement on small table
# Transform dataframe, and trigger action.
res = fact_table.join(
    dim_table.filter(dim_table["dim_val"] > 0),
    fact_table["fact_partition"] == dim_table["dim_key"],
    how = "left_semi",
)
res.collect()

>>> python3 foo.py
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join LeftSemi, (fact_partition#11L = dim_key#20L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
:- Filter (isnotnull(fact_partition#11L) AND dynamicpruning#30 [fact_partition#11L]), Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
:  :  +- Project [dim_key#20L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=759.0 B)
:  :     +- Filter ((isnotnull(dim_val#21L) AND (dim_val#21L > 0)) AND isnotnull(dim_key#20L)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
:  :        +- Relation foo_38072275409858.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
:  +- Relation foo_38072275409858.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
+- Project [dim_key#20L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=759.0 B)
   +- Filter ((isnotnull(dim_val#21L) AND (dim_val#21L > 0)) AND isnotnull(dim_key#20L)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
      +- Relation foo_38072275409858.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
+- == Final Plan ==
   *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [fact_partition#11L], [dim_key#20L], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
   :- *(2) ColumnarToRow
   :  +- FileScan parquet foo_38072275409858.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1000 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(fact_partition#11L), dynamicpruningexpression(fact_partition#11L IN dynamicpruning#30)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fact_id:bigint>
   :        +- SubqueryBroadcast dynamicpruning#30, 0, [dim_key#20L], [id=#96]
   :           +- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
               +- == Final Plan ==
                  BroadcastQueryStage 1
                  +- ReusedExchange [dim_key#20L], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, true]),false), [plan_id=68]
               +- == Initial Plan ==
                  BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, true]),false), [plan_id=88]
                  +- Project [dim_key#20L]
                     +- Filter ((isnotnull(dim_val#21L) AND (dim_val#21L > 0)) AND isnotnull(dim_key#20L))
                        +- FileScan parquet foo_38072275409858.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_val#21L), (dim_val#21L > 0), isnotnull(dim_key#20L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_val), GreaterThan(dim_val,0), IsNotNull(dim_key)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint,dim_val:bigint>
   +- BroadcastQueryStage 0
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, true]),false), [plan_id=68]
         +- *(1) Project [dim_key#20L]
            +- *(1) Filter ((isnotnull(dim_val#21L) AND (dim_val#21L > 0)) AND isnotnull(dim_key#20L))
               +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                  +- FileScan parquet foo_38072275409858.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_val#21L), (dim_val#21L > 0), isnotnull(dim_key#20L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_val), GreaterThan(dim_val,0), IsNotNull(dim_key)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint,dim_val:bigint>
+- == Initial Plan ==
   BroadcastHashJoin [fact_partition#11L], [dim_key#20L], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
   :- FileScan parquet foo_38072275409858.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1000 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(fact_partition#11L), dynamicpruningexpression(fact_partition#11L IN dynamicpruning#30)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fact_id:bigint>
   :     +- SubqueryAdaptiveBroadcast dynamicpruning#30, 0, true, Project [dim_key#20L], [dim_key#20L]
   :        +- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
   :           +- Project [dim_key#20L]
   :              +- Filter ((isnotnull(dim_val#21L) AND (dim_val#21L > 0)) AND isnotnull(dim_key#20L))
   :                 +- FileScan parquet foo_38072275409858.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_val#21L), (dim_val#21L > 0), isnotnull(dim_key#20L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_val), GreaterThan(dim_val,0), IsNotNull(dim_key)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint,dim_val:bigint>
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, true]),false), [plan_id=51]
      +- Project [dim_key#20L]
         +- Filter ((isnotnull(dim_val#21L) AND (dim_val#21L > 0)) AND isnotnull(dim_key#20L))
            +- FileScan parquet foo_38072275409858.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_val#21L), (dim_val#21L > 0), isnotnull(dim_key#20L)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_val), GreaterThan(dim_val,0), IsNotNull(dim_key)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint,dim_val:bigint>


0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3725)
1       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:191)
1       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3725)

Dynamic partition pruning kicks in!
Non-selective filter statement on small table (not dimension key/partition column)
# Transform dataframe, and trigger action.
res = fact_table.join(
    dim_table.filter(dim_table["dim_key"] > 0),
    fact_table["fact_partition"] == dim_table["dim_key"],
    how = "left_semi",
)
res.collect()

>>> python3 foo.py
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join LeftSemi, (fact_partition#11L = dim_key#20L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
:- Filter (((fact_partition#11L > 0) AND isnotnull(fact_partition#11L)) AND dynamicpruning#30 [fact_partition#11L]), Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
:  :  +- Project [dim_key#20L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=759.0 B)
:  :     +- Filter (isnotnull(dim_key#20L) AND (dim_key#20L > 0)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
:  :        +- Relation foo_38346293807150.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
:  +- Relation foo_38346293807150.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=481.4 KiB)
+- Project [dim_key#20L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=759.0 B)
   +- Filter (isnotnull(dim_key#20L) AND (dim_key#20L > 0)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)
      +- Relation foo_38346293807150.dim_table[dim_key#20L,dim_val#21L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1139.0 B)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
+- == Final Plan ==
   *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [fact_partition#11L], [dim_key#20L], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
   :- *(2) ColumnarToRow
   :  +- FileScan parquet foo_38346293807150.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1000 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [(fact_partition#11L > 0), isnotnull(fact_partition#11L), dynamicpruningexpression(fact_partition..., PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fact_id:bigint>
   :        +- SubqueryBroadcast dynamicpruning#30, 0, [dim_key#20L], [id=#89]
   :           +- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=true
               +- == Final Plan ==
                  BroadcastQueryStage 1
                  +- ReusedExchange [dim_key#20L], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=65]
               +- == Initial Plan ==
                  BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=83]
                  +- Filter (isnotnull(dim_key#20L) AND (dim_key#20L > 0))
                     +- FileScan parquet foo_38346293807150.dim_table[dim_key#20L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_key#20L), (dim_key#20L > 0)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_key), GreaterThan(dim_key,0)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint>
   +- BroadcastQueryStage 0
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=65]
         +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(dim_key#20L) AND (dim_key#20L > 0))
            +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
               +- FileScan parquet foo_38346293807150.dim_table[dim_key#20L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_key#20L), (dim_key#20L > 0)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_key), GreaterThan(dim_key,0)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint>
+- == Initial Plan ==
   BroadcastHashJoin [fact_partition#11L], [dim_key#20L], LeftSemi, BuildRight, false
   :- FileScan parquet foo_38346293807150.fact_table[fact_id#10L,fact_partition#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1000 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [(fact_partition#11L > 0), isnotnull(fact_partition#11L), dynamicpruningexpression(fact_partition..., PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fact_id:bigint>
   :     +- SubqueryAdaptiveBroadcast dynamicpruning#30, 0, true, Project [dim_key#20L], [dim_key#20L]
   :        +- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
   :           +- Filter (isnotnull(dim_key#20L) AND (dim_key#20L > 0))
   :              +- FileScan parquet foo_38346293807150.dim_table[dim_key#20L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_key#20L), (dim_key#20L > 0)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_key), GreaterThan(dim_key,0)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint>
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=52]
      +- Filter (isnotnull(dim_key#20L) AND (dim_key#20L > 0))
         +- FileScan parquet foo_38346293807150.dim_table[dim_key#20L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(dim_key#20L), (dim_key#20L > 0)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(dim_key), GreaterThan(dim_key,0)], ReadSchema: struct<dim_key:bigint>


0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:573)
0       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3725)
1       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:191)
1       collect at foo.py:46    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3725)

Dynamic partition pruning kicks in!
Compute statistics
# Create large partitioned facts table.
records = [
    {"fact_id": i + 1, "fact_partition": i + 1}
    for i in range(1000)
]
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        {"fact_id": i + 1, "fact_partition": i + 1}
        for i in range(1000)
    ],
).write.partitionBy(
    "fact_partition",
).saveAsTable(
    f"{schema_name}.fact_table",
)
spark.sql(f"ANALYZE TABLE {schema_name}.fact_table COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR ALL COLUMNS")
fact_table = spark.table(f"{schema_name}.fact_table")

# Create small dimension table.
records = [{"dim_key": 1, "dim_val": 1}]
spark.createDataFrame(
    [{"dim_key": 1, "dim_val": 1}],
).write.saveAsTable(
    f"{schema_name}.dim_table",
)
spark.sql(f"ANALYZE TABLE {schema_name}.dim_table COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR ALL COLUMNS")
dim_table = spark.table(f"{schema_name}.dim_table")

No effect.
Spark configuration
I tried a number cost-based optimizations:
spark = ps.SparkSession.builder.config(
    key = "spark.sql.cbo.enabled",
    value = True,
).config(
    key = "spark.sql.cbo.planStats.enabled",
    value = True,
).config(
    key = "spark.sql.statistics.histogram.enabled",
    value = True,
).getOrCreate()

No effect.

I have just noticed there is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728622/dynamic-partition-prunning-not-working-in-spark .
They follow a similar approach of doing non-selective things to the small table.
But there was no answer.
